# Passing multiple arguments at the time of using switcher in Python

Tags: python

```
device_properties = ['Device Category', 'Device Count', 'Device Cost']

switcher = {
                'Device Category': get_device_category(index),
                'Device Count': get_device_count(index),
                'Device Cost': get_device_cost(index)
            }        

for index in range(10):
     for j in device_properties:
         cat_data[cat] = switcher.get(j, 0)
```

Now I want to send "index" also as argument at the time of calling `switcher.get(j, 0)`. i.e.,
`switcher.get((j,index), 0)` so that I can use value of index in my functions that I defined in switcher dict.
So, Is there any way to send multiple arguments at the time of `switcher.get(j, 0)` or any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store pointers to functions and call them when accessing:

```
switcher = {
    'Device Category': get_device_category,
    'Device Count': get_device_count,
    'Device Cost': get_device_cost,
}        

for index in range(10):
     for j in device_properties:
         cat_data[cat] = switcher.get(j)(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, by storing pointers I am able to use multiple arguments in functions.

Comment: Is there any way to send different-different arguments in above functions, i.e. if I want to send like this:
`get_device_category(index)` 
`get_device_count(j, index)`

Comment: Of course, check how `*args*` and `**kwargs` is used in python